# Yet more on Manipulate[] - Formated Input

Tags: manipulate, formatting, gui-construction, free-form-input

Suppose I have something like

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {n, 20, "Frequency"}]
```

with a manual input field but I want to accept inputs like `20 Hz`. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

```
Manipulate[

  Plot[Sin[hz x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]

, { {input, "1 Hz", "Frequency"}
  , InputField[#, String, ##2] &
  , TrackingFunction :> Function[
      new
    , Catch[
        hz = Check[
          QuantityMagnitude[Interpreter["Quantity"] @ new, "Hertz"]
        , Throw @ $Failed
        ]
      ; input = new
      ]
    ]
  }
, {{hz, 1}, None} (*just for scoping*)
]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, whoever edited the question screwed up. My original question was about % input, so if you input 20% it should be passed on as 0.2 (so, you want to transform the input in a fixed way).

Comment: But looks like the right thing, thanks!

Comment: @IgorRivin it was me because it was slightly confusing. If you want we can revert it and add clarification.